# JW Player, Google analytics.js, and Events

Tags: google-analytics, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I'm trying to use analytics.js with JW Player. Page view works and I can send my own events. However I am not seeing the JW events for Video Plays, Video Completes, and Seconds Played such as I used to get with previous version of the player using the older GA script.

I have read [JW's docs](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1417179-integration-with-google-analytics) but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-34936065-2', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script>
ga('send', 'event', 'This is an Event Category', 'An Action Type', 'An event label' );
</script>
</style>
    <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/7QL57lXFEeKkiSIACp8kUw.js"></script><script>jwplayer.key="iE4DX1FvqagyymuKRD+RHWzV5OVPIjQx13H8Mg==";</script><div id='mediaplayer'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
        file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/vM7nH0Kl-640.mp4',
        ga: { }
});
</script><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use JW Player google analytics plugin you need premium/ ads/ enterprise edition.

You're using Pro edition.

Comment: In JW 6 Enterprise, did we lose one of my very most favorite features of JW 5 Google Analytics, which was triggering events containing Seconds Played and Percentage Played?

If so, that is really too bad. I suppose there is a way to use the API to restore those features. But I got a lot of value from knowing total Seconds Played in any period.